# Tweetpy cannot search anything. How to apply for Elevated access?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I use twitter developer free version. I try use tweetpy search data from twitter like this code.

```
from tweepy import OAuthHandler

consumer_key = 'xxxxxxx'
consumer_secret = 'xxxxxxx'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
client = tweepy.API(auth)

for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(client.search_tweets, q='covid',
                           count=100).items(250):
    print(tweet.id_str)
```

It show error like this.

```
Forbidden: 403 Forbidden
453 - You currently have Essential access which includes access to Twitter API v2 endpoints only. If you need access to this endpoint, you’ll need to apply for Elevated access via the Developer Portal. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-leve
```

I'm not found menu to apply Elevated access. How to apply for Elevated access?

Comment: Given the recent restructuring of twitter chances are you cannot use that api with paying serious $$$.